# Different JAVA Versions in a single springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am not well versed on Java Spring Boot. I am asking for help here. Flow is this - a Message Streaming platform (supports only Java 8) --> Consumer --> Data Lake Platform (Supports only Java 11).

So We need to write a Consumer app on Spring boot consume a message from Streaming platform and update/insert into the Data Lake Platform. For now, wwe are trying to create two different springboot apps to consume and write. I wanted to know if we can have only one app (which can support multiple Java version based on source and destination). Is it even possible or not.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question/problem: how do the messages you receive and send depend on the Java version? Are all three things not on independent machines?

Comment: you cannot use 2 different java versions when for 1 executable

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. You can run two JVM processes on one physical server using different Java executables, sure... **However**...

> based on source and destination

This shouldn't matter. From what I understand, those are external services, and do not affect the serialization formats your Spring app would be able to use, as a stream consumer or data-lake client.

In fact, Java JRE 11 can run compiled "Java 8 code", so it would make more sense to simply update the Java version on the streaming platform side, if at all possible.

Same answer should apply to any Java framework, not only Spring. You may even be able to write such service without Java/Spring...